# How (if possible) can I set the duration of a CGAffineTransformRotate

Tags: objective-c, ios

I Have a standard CGAffineTransformRotate in my code rotating a CALayer. I haven't been able to work out how to set the duration of the animation.

Any Ideas?

Thank you David I was able to find what I needed thanks to your comment. Sometimes I think you just need a fresh perspective after staring at a screen for 8 hours, Cheers.

Jake

[The developer doc. The answer is buried in here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html)

Comment: The same way you specify the animation duration for everything else? how are you animating? Implicitly? If so, change to explicit animation so that you can specify the duration..

Comment: Make sure to post your answer and mark it as correct (once you are able to do so).

Answer (score 2):

this code may help you

```
// if you dont use this code with a UIButton cange the UIButton befor the "animateWithDuration:"

- (IBAction)rotate:(id)sender {

        [UIButton animateWithDuration:1.0 /* <---- duration of the animation (float)*/

                           animations:^{   /*block for animation*/

                               CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 360 /* <---- Rotation degrees*/ / 180.0 * M_PI );
                               [button setTransform:rotate];

                             }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){ /*code block triggerd when animation is done*/ }];

        // if here is an NSLog it wil probably be triggerd befor the animation ends

    }
```